# canonical bundle skew-symmetric determinantal varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

By a skew-symmetric determinantal variety (over $\mathbb{C}$), I mean the projectivization of the set of skew-symmetric matrices of fixed size which rank is less than a given integer. 
More precisely, let $V$ be a fixed vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$ and let $r \leq n$ be an even integer. Let me define:

$$ \mathbb{P}f_r(V) := \mathbb{P} \{ v \in \bigwedge^2 V, \, rk(v) \leq r \}.$$

It is well-known that all $\mathbb{P}f_r(V)$ are Gorenstein. Let's consider the natural embedding $\mathbb{P}f_r(V) \subset \mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V)$. I suspect that the dualizing sheaf of $\mathbb{P}f_r(V)$ is a power of the restriction $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V)}(1)$ to $\mathbb{P}f_r(V)$.

It is obvious if $r=2$ (Grassmannian case) and I can prove it for $r=4$. I would like to know if there is a reference for the general case (with a precise formula $\omega_{\mathbb{P}f_r(V)} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}f_r(V)}(???)$).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Find a resolution and compute its canonical class --- it will be a sum of a multiple of the pullback of a hyperplane on $P(\Lambda^2V)$ and a multiple of the exceptional divisor. The first summand is what you want.